# Selenium iframe upload image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, file-upload

So, I'm trying to upload image with Selenium Python. Here is what's supposed to do:

1. First I click on the button
   [image]
2. It opens up a file window
3. I choose which file I want to upload
4. The file uploads to my website with the preview shown and a link to the image is generated on the field below
   [image]

Here is what I got so far:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
upload_image = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@id='drop']/input[@name='images']")
upload_image.send_keys("C:/Users/Pictures/banner1.png")
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

When I run the script, there are no errors and I think the image successfully upload(?). But the image preview didn't display and the image link is not generated.
[image]

Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">
   <section id="main-content">
      <form id="upload">
         <div id="drop">
            <a>点击上传</a>
            <div class="progress invensible"></div>
            <div class="file-types"></div>
            <script></script>
            <input type="file" name="images" multiple>
         </div>
      </form>
   </section>
</div>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: some times on inspect it focus on input but may not work in script.. mostly in case of uploads, try id=drop

Comment: @muraliselenium so I don't have to locate to the input too? just the div id='drop'?

Comment: tried only id='drop' but it gives an error saying ```Message: element not interactable``` @muraliselenium

Comment: What url is this>

Comment: the website? it's actually not open to public @ArundeepChohan

Comment: I was thinking maybe following the same concept of clicking on the button and then sending the file over. So driver.find_element("link_text", "点击上传]").click()

Comment: is it possible for selenium to locate the file explorer? @ArundeepChohan

Comment: @aufa instead of click in first step.. try upload there itself

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it? @muraliselenium

Comment: @aufa instead of click, inspect that button.. see any locator for input or something like that.. use it for sendkeys with file location

Comment: When you add a picture does value / property of any element changes?

Comment: Selenium can't interact with the browser's File | Open dialog... passing the value to the upload INPUT, as you are already doing it, is the correct way.

Comment: I'm assuming you can follow all these steps manually and everything works? After your `.send_keys()` to the INPUT, if you pause the script there does it eventually work? I'm wondering if it's a timing issue.

Comment: You might also open the site in Chrome and once you have the upload dialog loaded, open the devtools (F12) and then type `$x("//div[@id='drop']/input[@name='images']")` in the console. Does it only return 1 element?

Comment: it returns this ```[input]
0: input
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)``` @JeffC

Comment: OK. That means that there's only one element that is found by that locator so that's good. What about the answers to my previous questions?

Comment: eh sorry, it returns this ```length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)``` @JeffC